# The Art of Computer Programming MIX MUL Instruction

Tags: windows

I am going through *Art of Computer Programming* (Knuth's) MIX instruction.

I am trying to understand the `MUL 1000` instruction as below:

```
| + | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |    [rA before] 

| + | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |    [Cell 1000]

| + | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |    [rA after]

| + | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |    [rX After]
```

Is there a way to know why `rA` and `rX` has got that values?

Kindly help!

[Image of the particular page in the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/291tA.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The multiplication instruction of MIX is defined as, [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIX):

`MUL ADDR,i(0:5) --> (rA,rX) := rA * memory[ADDR + rIi];`

That means that the values of the accumulator register `rA` and of the memory address `ADDR + rIi`, where `rIi` is an index register, are multiplied. The result of the multiplication is stored into the accumulator register `rA` and the extension register `rX`.

Also the following holds:

> MIX is a hybrid binary–decimal computer.

Therefore the calculation is done by simply using a long multiplication as follows, where `Cell 1000` comes from the command `MUL 1000` without usage of an index register `rIi`. The identifier `Cell 1000` means the address where `1 1 1 1 1` is stored, it is not the value itself.

```
rA:            1 1 1 1 1
Cell 1000:   * 1 1 1 1 1
     ___________________
               1 1 1 1 1
             1 1 1 1 1
           1 1 1 1 1
         1 1 1 1 1
       1 1 1 1 1
     ___________________
     0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
     |   rA   |   rX   |

rA = 0 1 2 3 4
rX = 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: Hi @Swaminathan if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.